# asp.net login Page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I have an asp.net webpage.  I want the other pages to expire when the user clicks the logout button.  Im not using the login control, im just using a textbox for the login page.  When the user enters username and password, i check to see if that matches with the one in the database.  How do i make it so when the user logs out, they cant click the back button, or just cant type the specific URL without goin through the login page first

Answer (score 1):

This should be automatically handled by ASP.NET. Make sure that you are abandoning the Session when the user clicks logout and you have the configuration similar to this in web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">  
<forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"  
       defaultUrl="Default.aspx" timeout="30"   
       slidingExpiration="true"/>  
</authentication>
```

Comment: still dosnt work. I was able to click the back button and go back to the previos page

Comment: When you click back, the browser just loads the page from cache without contacting the server. IMHO that's default behavior. That's the reason most transaction sites suggest user to close the browser window once they are done.

Comment: but how to you make it secure like other sites.  For most sites with secure data, when u log out, you wont be able to click back, if you try to click back usally it sends you back to the login page or tells you the page expires

Answer (score 0):

Try this is page load event

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            Response.Redirect("your_redirecting_url");
        }
```